# UITabBarController Issues with Storyboard References

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, xcode7, storyboard-reference

1. I have four storyboard files in the project.
2. In the "TabView.storyboard", I create three Storyboard Reference instances and link them to the other storyboard respectively.

[image]

3. Then I run the app in the simulator and device. The title and icon image on the tab bar item just don't appear(both on simulator and device).
   [image]

**However**, if I crate the UITabBarController and it's view controllers in common way, and use "Editor->Refactor to storyboard" option in the menu, the titles and icon images show normally.

It this a bug of Xcode7?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Seems like a similar issue to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33182982/uitabbarcontroller-issues-with-storyboard-references). I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33759963/97705).

> You need to add the tab bar item in the destination storyboard view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Can you ensure that the entry point of the storyboard is the TabBarController itself? This looks similar to an issue I saw before where the person had declared that the storyboard entry point be in the HomeViewController instead of the TabBarController, which results in the app starting on the HomeViewController but lacking the actual tabs.

If you select a controller in the story board there should be a checkbox to flag that controller as the entry point.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the "Is Initial View Controller" of the UITabBarController is checked. And you can also see the entry arrow on the TabBarController in my first screenshot.